# How to trigger event after rendering Polymer element?

Tags: javascript, polymer

I'm implementing a search list element, but I have trouble showing the current count of search result. It is always showing the result of my previous step. Is there way to get the value (or trigger the event) after the DOM finished rendering?

Here is the code:

```
//main
<template>
  <items-list
    items="{{items}}"
    search="{{search}}">
  </items-list>
  count: {{count}}
</template>
<script>
  Polymer({
    searchChanged: function () {
      this.count = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('items-list').getCount();
    }
  });
</script>

//item-list
<polymer-element name="items-list" attributes="search items">
  <template>
    <template repeat="{{item in items}}">
      <item
        hidden?="{{toHide(search, item.name)}}"
        item="{{item}}">
      </item>
    </template>
  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({
      toHide: function (search, breedName) {
        //...
      },

      getCount: function () {
        var items = this.shadowRoot.querySelectorAll('item:not([hidden])');

        return items.length;
      }
    });
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

Answer (score 0):

`polymer-ready` event is fired by Polymer when all the custom elements are loaded on to the page.

You can use listen to this event and respond accordingly like in the example below.

```
// in you main html page
window.addEventListener('polymer-ready', function(e){

// rest of your code

});
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think this is what I need.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a race condition. The DOM has not updated by the time you query for the count. This is a common issue in Polymer, which is why we have [the job method](https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/polymer.html#job). It automatically debounces for you and preserves your scope. Pretty handy! Try something like this:

```
<template>
  <items-list
    items="{{items}}"
    search="{{search}}">
  </items-list>
  count: {{count}}
</template>
<script>
  Polymer({
    searchChanged: function () {
      this.job(function() {
        this.count = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('items-list').getCount();
      }, 100);
    }
  });
</script>
```